# How to keep java JDBC connection to oracle secured

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am building a web application with java and using JDBC driver

please tell me if i wrong, i dont think using this block of code is secured
how should i make it secured without using "HARD CODED" password

```
Connection connection = null;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mkyong","username","password");
connection.close();
```

taken from:
    http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/

Comment: Depending on the web server, you could configure a connection pool which would take the settings from a configuration file

Comment: The password would already be encrypted going over the network.  Have a look at the JDBC documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/clntsec.htm#EHAFHEIG.

Comment: You haven't needed the `Class.forName()` line since 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're building a web-app your resources should be declared externally, for example in a Tomcat Context.xml file. The password will be located there, not in your code. And keeping that secure is a matter of physical security.

Answer (score 1):

Java code will be executed on the server if you mean a Tomcat web application for example. So it should be ok so.

**But** if you want to have more security you could create a credentials.properties file, with tomcat as owner and rights of 600. Then you read username and password from that file.

And of course you could encrypt it in the file.

**EDIT**: And the credentials.properties file should not be accessable over the web ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try Jasypt and it should help:
http://jasypt.org/

Example (Using a .properties file mechanism):

Step1: Find out encrypted password and make a note of it for usage:
    StrongPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();
    String encryptedPassword = passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword(userPassword);

Let's say the encryptedPassword is: G6N718UuyPE5bHyWKyuLQSm02auQPUtm

Step2: Store DB connection credentials in a .properties file with encrypted password
    datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/reportsdb
    datasource.username=reportsUser
    datasource.password=ENC(G6N718UuyPE5bHyWKyuLQSm02auQPUtm)

Step3: How do we read this value? like this:

```
/*
 * First, create (or ask some other component for) the adequate encryptor for
 * decrypting the values in our .properties file.
*/
StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
encryptor.setPassword("jasypt"); // could be got from web, env variable...

/*
 * Create our EncryptableProperties object and load it the usual way.
 */
Properties props = new EncryptableProperties(encryptor);
props.load(new FileInputStream("/path/to/my/configuration.properties"));

/*
 * To get a non-encrypted value, we just get it with getProperty...
 */
String datasourceUsername = props.getProperty("datasource.username");

/*
 * ...and to get an encrypted value, we do exactly the same. Decryption will
 * be transparently performed behind the scenes.
 */ 
String datasourcePassword = props.getProperty("datasource.password");

// From now on, datasourcePassword equals "reports_passwd"...
```

For decrypting the encrypted value, we just had to access it with getProperty, just as with any other non-encrypted value.

Details here: http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html

Comment: Try it why? Help how? Link-only answers are not sufficient here.

Comment: Hi @EJP, Jsypt home page itself has the example to encrypt password. I could copy paste the code here but felt the page has it and should be sufficient. However, will edit the answer for ease.